# Postgresql: How to remove duplicate rows while joining?

Tags: postgresql, join, postgresql-9.3, materialized-views

I have two postgresql table called `charges` and `orders`. I'm trying to create a matview with the data of how many charges turned into orders and it's worth. The two tables are not directly related, here's the table structure of both

```
Charges

| date   | transaction_id | amount |
|--------|----------------|--------|
| 23-Apr | abcdef         | 36     |
| 23-Apr | fghijkl        | 198    |
| 24-Apr | yyyyyy         | 200    |

Orders

| date   | order_id |
|--------|----------|
| 23-Apr | abcdef   |
| 23-Apr | abcdef   |
| 24-Apr | yyyyyy   |
```

And below is the query I'm using for generating the matview,

```
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW sales AS
    SELECT ch.date AS date,
           (ord.id IS NOT NULL) as placed_order,
           COUNT(DISTINCT(ch.transaction_id)) AS attempts,
           SUM(ch.amount) AS amount
    FROM charges ch
    LEFT OUTER JOIN orders as ord ON ch.transaction_id = ord.order_id
    GROUP BY ch.date
```

The problem is caused by the `Amount` column generated in the view. Due to the duplicates in `orders` table multiple rows of `charges` are returned during the left outer join and the amount is basically increasing.

Is there an way to `Distinct` the `order_id` column from orders at the time of joining itself?

Or is there a way to distinct the `order_id` and sum the amount at the time of query itself? I tried sub-query and self-join but to no luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make a sub-query on table `orders` to filter out the duplicates:

```
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW sales AS
  SELECT ch.date AS date,
         (ord.order_id IS NOT NULL) AS placed_order,
         count(ch.transaction_id) AS attempts,
         sum(ch.amount) AS amount
  FROM charges ch
  LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT DISTINCT date, order_id FROM orders) ord ON ch.transaction_id = ord.order_id
  GROUP BY 1, 2
```

Comment: That still gives the duplicate data added up. Try removing the `DISTINCT` from `count(DISTINCT(ch.transaction_id))` the count varies..

Comment: Sorry, it only is not working when `id` is added to the `SELECT` statement in the join.

Comment: From the question, in combination with the sample query you give, it is not really clear over what set of rows you want to do the aggregation. Please try to edit your question and I'll have another look, if you need more help.